# Bringing Dirham to Morocco

Tags: legal, exchange, morocco

We are Italians, we will go 4 days to Marrakech in October. We exhanged 250€ in Dirham from an Italian fx office (a well known fx company) but then we discovered that it is forbidden to bring Dirham outside Morocco and formally exchange outside the country is forbidden.

Do you know if there are risks in bringing those Dirham to Morocco? If it is forbidden to bring them out then I suppose you could not enter with them. Are there custom forms to fill when entering the country that might ask if we own Dirham?

Comment: You'll be in trouble if you get checked at customs. That's about it. I would get the fx company to return the exchanged money without fees since they're not supposed to exchange it anyways and should have told you in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I have been to Morocco many times. I would Highly suggest not to take Dirhams with you from your own country because as above JoErNanO said that there will be a problem if you caught by the customs. You can easily exchange currency in Morocco. Its okay to exchange currency in Morocco at any currency exchange outlet.

Comment: After clearing customs in Morocco, a lot of the foreigners head straight to the airport ATMs. The exchange rate might not be great, but I'd rather do that than risk a customs check.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the low amount of currency involved we took the risk (the fx company would have charged 25% commission to get back the Dirhams).

At the customs there is just a simple form to fill, with no questions about money. Checks are quite good, including x-ray also of hand baggage before exiting the safe zone. It is true that on airport and in Marrakech it is easy to find exchanges that apply a reasonable rate, so the risk is not worthwhile.

Moreover most people accept Euros without problems, they apply a 1 EUR = 10 DH conversion, which is just a bit worse than the one applied by the Italian fx company.